# Query to obtain random 4 products per shop

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’m trying to display 4 random products for each shop if the product stock exists.I have 3 tables: one for the shop info– “ws_shop_official”, one for  products – “ws_product” and one that stores product image information – “ ws_product_pic”.

Using the below statement, the result returned are random however I’m not getting exactly 4 products (rows) returned per shop.

```
select prod.product_id,prod.shop_id,prod.product_name,prod.normal_price,prod.stock,prod.create_time,prod.product_id,official.shop_id,img.file_name,img.file_path
from ws_product prod
join ws_shop_official official ON prod.shop_id = official.shop_id 
join ws_product_pic img ON prod.product_id = img.product_id 
where prod.stock > 0 AND prod.shop_id IN (select shop_id from ws_shop_official where status=1 )
order by prod.create_time DESC
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

The expected solution is 4 product info rows per shop.
Also is it better to query once or multiple times in loop for each shop id?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the expected result from that sample data?

Answer (score 0):

We use PL/PgSQL for this, first we calculate the total number of rows that match a certain search criteria:

```
    recnum := count(p.id) from
        stt_group g,
        stt_product p
    left join
        stt_image i
    on
        i.product = p.id
    and
        i.is_default = true
    and
        i.is_public = true
    where
        p.pgroup = g.id
    and
        g.id = group_id
    and
        p.online_shop = true;
```

And then we calculate how much percent all records correspond to the number of rows we want, which we have in the 'size' variable:

```
    percentage := 100.0 * size::numeric / recnum::numeric;
    if percentage > 100.0 then
        percentage = 100.0;
    end if;
```

Finally we use tablesample to the required random percentage of records:

```
    return query select
        p.id,
        p.name,
        p.price,
        p.stock_qty,
        p.stock_minqty,
        i.id,
        p.nr
    from
        stt_group g,
        stt_product p tablesample bernoulli(percentage)
    left join
        stt_image i
    on
        i.product = p.id
    and
        i.is_default = true
    and
        i.is_public = true
    where
        p.pgroup = g.id
    and
        g.id = group_id
    and
        p.online_shop = true
    order by
        p.name
    limit
        size;
```

While this works, keep in mind that tablesample returns "roughly" the percentage, it maybe a few more or less, that's why we limit the number of returned rows.

Comment: We use PostgreSQL 9.6, fwiw.